# How can I get data in power BI from other power BI files

Tags: database, powerbi, dax, powerquery, data-modeling

I created a large .pbix file on my local drive trying to extract infomation from several hunderd webpages and combine them. Like this:

```
myfile.pbix
    query_001
    query_002
    ...
    query_904
    combined_query
```

But it takes hours to open and refresh. So I grouped the queries in power query and put them in small individual .pbix files on the local drive as below. There are only data with no models and reports.

```
myfile1.pbix
    query_001
    query_002

myfile2.pbix
    query_003
    query_004

...

myfile44.pbix
    query_903
    query_904
```

How can I get them togther again? I cannot find such a function as "import data from .pbix files". Do I have to publish them first? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was in your shoe once and I know how slow power query refresh can be. Power query is awesome but it may not be suitable for complex application. However, you can apply following fix and see how it works in your case.

A. If you use power bi service, you can create dataflow using power query and have them refreshed at a scheduled time. You can then query those dataflows in a pbi desktop, create model and solve business problem. By using dataflow in a subsequent seperate pbix, you are divinding and distributing the transformation and modelling. Dataflow are connected to Azure deta lake and if gateways are configured correctly and memory allocation are done appropriately, refresh are much faster than pbix desktop.

B. Second option is to use SSIS. SSIS has power query connector. (You can use something else too inside SSIS, not necessarily PQWRY).So whatver power query you have written to query the datasource you can wrap those inside a SSIS package, scheduled and have the ETL result pushed to a SQL server. You can schedule the SSIS job and you can build pbix model only by querying the SQL tables. The benefit is if you need to apply further transformation, you can wrote native SQL queries which are blazing fast compared to Power Query. In this way you are avoiding a ELT+modelling to ETL and subsequent modelling. ETL and modelling runs seperately and not in the same package, hence way faster.

C. If you use Power BI service, you can publish each of the data sources in service and then query simply the powerbi dataset for modeling. If you want, you can also use power bi's new awesome composite modeling.

Comment: Thanks! I'm also wondering if i can use power query independently. Where else can I use power query other than excel, powerbi, and ssis?

Comment: Azure Data Factory so far apart from excel, pbi and ssis